# How to execute this openssl command in an .ex file?

Tags: openssl, elixir

I'm trying to execute this command in an .ex file -

```
openssl ec -in myprivatekey.pem -outform DER|tail -c +8|head -c 32|xxd -p -c 32
```

, which I've translated to

```
  {_, 0} = System.cmd "openssl", [ "ec", "-in", private_key_file, "-outform", "DER|tail", "-c", "+8|head", "-c", "32|xxd", "-p", "-c", "32"], [stderr_to_stdout: true]
```

in elixir, but im getting the following error - 
[image: error]

How to correctly execute this openssl command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code snippet is actually executing multiple commands (openssl, tail, head, xxd) and piping data from one to the next. `System.cmd` spawns only one command and does not automatically handle pipes.

You can use `:os.cmd/1` to execute this, which will spawn the command using the system's default shell, which should handle pipes:

```
# Note that this takes the command as a charlist and does not return the exit code
output = :os.cmd('openssl ec -in myprivatekey.pem -outform DER|tail -c +8|head -c 32|xxd -p -c 32')
```

Another way is to pass the command to a shell yourself using `System.cmd`. The following should work on systems that have `/bin/sh` present:

```
{stdout, 0} = System.cmd("/bin/sh", ["-c", "openssl ec -in myprivatekey.pem -outform DER|tail -c +8|head -c 32|xxd -p -c 32"])
```